# convert promise JSON return in a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

My promise returns a JSON like this:

```
‘[ {"amazing data": "hello", "amazing again": "yep"}, {"amazing data": "hello", "amazing again": "yep"}]’
```

I would just like to return an array of objects:

```
[
 {"amazing data": "hello", "amazing again": "yep"},
 {"amazing data": "hello", "amazing again": "yep"}
]
```

I would like to access it this way because I can work with reduce after the promise returns.

My code:

```
const amazingPromise = await getData().then((data) => {
   return data
})


const prodArray = Array.from(amazingPromise.reduce((acc, o) => {
    Object.entries(o)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if(!acc.has(k)) acc.set(k, [k])
        
        acc.get(k).push(Array.isArray(v) ? v.join(' | ') : v)
      })
    
    return acc
  }, new Map()).values())
```

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Why does your promise return a string of things rather than actual valid JSON? Your output isn't valid either.

Comment: read the string, detect `}` and append it to your array.. and so on until you finish reading the string, and then you can parse the json object as a test

Comment: I edited the question. The promise returns a JSON valid obj.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires double quotes around all strings, including object keys.

Comment: If you copied it wrong, and it's really valid JSON, use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Change `return data` to `return JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Please update your post to show real data. Don't show "something that looks like", show (redacted) real data. In this case: JSON does not have fancy quotes around them, and the parts inside the quotes are entirely not JSON. And if your function _actually_ generates that literal string, then explicitly mention that and don't call it JSON until you get to the part where you _do_ expect to be working with JSON. (because terminology always matters for technical questions =)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that is not achieved with `const amazingData = await getData().then(data => JSON.parse(data))`?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Web project, you can use react.State() for solve this.
For example, in my projects, I use the state to save the results of an API request like your example.

```
const App = ()=>{
    const[array, setArray] = useState([]); //Init the array as a empty array
    
    useEffect( ()=>{
      const RequestAPI = async ()=>{
           const URL = "https://...";
           const response = await fetch(URL);
           const newArray = await response.json();
           setArray(newArray);
      };
      RequestAPI();
     },[]);
     
    return (
      {array.map(item => <ComponentItem /> ) }
}
```

Try to use something similar to state and async functions in your project as its possible